# OpenGL North, East, South, West

Tags: opengl

I am fully aware that "directional-based-orientation" in a 3D space is completely arbitrary, much like in outer space there exists no up or down; it is based on perception. However, I am curious, are there any common conventions when it comes to declaring something is facing North? Could Positive X be considered North?

EDIT:
I just remembered that Minecraft has a directional-based output in the debug console; it seems they orient like this:

Positive X: East

Negative X: West

Positive Z: South

Negative Z: North

I decided to stick with how Minecraft declares its directional facings; I wrote this small helper class too. The switch parse method is unnecessary but I wanted it anyway.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourNameSpaceHere {

    public static class Orientation {
        public const double North = 180.0D;
        public const double East = -90.0D;
        public const double South = 0.0D;
        public const double West = 90.0D;

        public enum Direction {
            North ,
            East ,
            South ,
            West
        }

        public static double ParseRotation( Direction direction ) {
            double returnVal = 0.0D;
            switch( direction ) {
                case Direction.North:
                    returnVal = North;
                    break;
                case Direction.East:
                    returnVal = East;
                    break;
                case Direction.South:
                    returnVal = South;
                    break;
                case Direction.West:
                    returnVal = West;
                    break;
            }
            return returnVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Minecraft orientation probably has its origin in a default camera setup in which you're looking in the negative direction of Z axis. So it's natural it would be treated as north just as you look in the direction of north while looking at a real-life map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no conventions when it comes to assigning world directions to specific axis in OpenGL, but I would say that common sense suggests naming it the way you described it in your EDIT.

I think that it's quite clear to assume that the default direction to which user is facing when looking at the screen is north, therefore -Z: North, Z: South, -X: West, X: East. But it's really up to you how you name those directions, so if you feel like different approach is more suggestive for you, you can go for it.

Please, note also that when you work with 2D map, you'd change the way of thinking about world directions.